# msdeploy: allowuntrusted is being ignored

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, msdeploy

I have a machine [A] running fresh installation of Win2008 R2 which holds a webapp on IIS. I try to use `msdeploy` command line tool on machine [B] to publish a deployment package to this machine, but i keep on getting error regarding certificate. 
I am using `-allowuntrusted`, but it still keeps on giving the same error.

I've been trying different things (like changing msdeploy port on IIS, installing certificate on the other machine, reinstall iis roles, tons of other) for 2 days now with absolutely no luck.

This is what I run:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="Web.zip" -dest:auto,ComputerName="https://machineA:8173/msdeploy.axd?site=app.com",UserName="AdminUser",Password="SecurePassword",AuthType="Basic" -allowUntrusted
```

To make things more interesting, this is what I get when I run the same command on the IIS-containing machine (even after changing dest to sync):

```
Error: A '-dest' argument must be specified with the 'sync' verb.
Error count: 1.
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I tried using the same settings (ip, package, authentication) in Visual Studio 2012 to create a publishing profile which deploys. After hitting "Verify connection", I got a popup asking if I want to accept this untrusted certificate. I clicked yes and went on to publish - that went through just fine.

Is there a way to get this behaviour with msdeploy command line? Using VS2012 is not an option for me, since publishing must be done automatically.

EDIT 2: 
The fun continues: it works on another Windows Server 2008 R2 target machine (not a clean install though). So, where's the magic checkbox? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I managed to figure out 2 solutions:

1. Get a valid certificate (we had one in company, so playing around with hosts on machine [B] to match IP with company's domain, helped).
2. Place "-allowUntrusted:true" BEFORE "-dest" instead of at the end. No clue why does it work on one but not another machine.

Hope this helps someone to save some time :)

Comment: -allowUntrusted can be placed anywhere. if it works before the "-dest" then that means you have some problem with double quotes or with hyphen itself which are making msdeploy.exe not see the allowuntrusted being passed to it. Such as a hyphen copied from word doc or outlook email

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems with the command:

Unless you have changed the default port, you should be using 8172 and not 8173.

Secondly there is a double quote before securepassword but I don't see a closing double quote.

Your package most likely has some default parameters for which you must be specifying values during deployment.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="Web.zip" -dest:auto,ComputerName=https://machineA:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=app.com,UserName="AdminUser",Password="SecurePassword",AuthType="Basic" -allowUntrusted -setParam:paramname=value
```

Comment: I changed port in attempt to make things work. Since I get certificate and not "destination unreachable" error, I assume connection goes through just fine. Even went through registry to see that port changes are applied everywhere.

Double quote: sorry, my mistake. Fixed it in original question, quote is also present in the real query (just checked the script).
As for other parameters, I have specified them when building the deployment package (using msbuild and bunch of params) and therefore I don't add anything else here.

As I said, this command works on a different machine.